# how can i load list of url image inside DefaultClusterRenderer class

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

i have problem when I tried to load list of image by imageloader library
inside many marks by ClusterRenderer

I was asked to create a similar page

[image]

1- I got location by query in firebase database

```
   override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            mGoogleMap?.clear()
            var arrays=ArrayList<FirebaseUserModel>()
            for(item in snapshot.children){
                var user: FirebaseUserModelMArks?=item.getValue(FirebaseUserModelMArks::class.java)
                if(!user!!.firebaseID.equals(firebaseid)){
                    mClusterManager!!.addItem(user)
                    mClusterManager!!.cluster();
                    
                        }

            }
```

2-i added class for cluster render to show images like previous picture

class UserRender(context: Context, map: GoogleMap,clusterManager: ClusterManager
) : DefaultClusterRenderer(context, map, clusterManager) {

```
private var iconGenerator: IconGenerator? = null
private var clusterIconGenerator: IconGenerator? = null
private var imageView: ImageView? = null
private var clusterImageView: ImageView? = null
private var markerWidth = 0
private var markerHeight = 0
private val TAG = "ClusterRenderer"


init {
    clusterIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context.applicationContext)
    val clusterView: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custome_mark, null)
    clusterIconGenerator!!.setContentView(clusterView)
    clusterImageView = clusterView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)



    iconGenerator = IconGenerator(context.applicationContext)
    imageView = ImageView(context.applicationContext)
    markerWidth = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.d6).toInt()
    markerHeight = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.d6).toInt()
    imageView!!.setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth, markerHeight))
    val padding =
        context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.d1).toInt()
    imageView!!.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding)
    iconGenerator!!.setContentView(imageView)



}

override fun onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem: FirebaseUserModelMArks?, marker: Marker?) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        BasicTools.loadImage(clusterItem?.image!!,imageView!!,object : DownloadListener {
        override fun completed(status: Boolean, bitmap: Bitmap) {
            imageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            val icon = iconGenerator!!.makeIcon(clusterItem?.name)
            marker!!.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
            marker.isVisible=true

        }
    })}
}






/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/


override fun onClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<FirebaseUserModelMArks>?, marker: Marker?) {
    super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker)
    val iterator: Iterator<FirebaseUserModelMArks> = cluster!!.items.iterator()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    BasicTools.loadImage(
        iterator.next()?.image!!,
        clusterImageView!!,
        object : DownloadListener {
            override fun completed(status: Boolean, bitmap: Bitmap) {
                clusterImageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                Log.i("TEST_TEST", "${iterator.next().name}----------------")
                val icon = iconGenerator!!.makeIcon(iterator.next()?.name)
                marker!!.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))

            }
        })
}
}

override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<FirebaseUserModelMArks>?): Boolean {
    return cluster!!.getSize() > 1
}
```

}

3-loadImage function has this parameters

fun loadImage(url: String, image_view: ImageView, listener: DownloadListener?)

The problem is that the application can only display one image from the list
It cannot display all images

what wrong in code ?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for same?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using functions that repeat themselves

```
  private fun saveBitmap(arrays: ArrayList<FirebaseUserModelMArks>,firstLanuch:Boolean=false) {
    if(firstLanuch)
    index=arrays.size-1
    if(index>=0){
        BasicTools.loadImage(arrays.get(index).image!!,iv_test!!,object : DownloadListener {
            override fun completed(status: Boolean, bitmap: Bitmap) {
                //   iv_test!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

                arrays.get(index).imageBitmap=bitmap
                mClusterManager!!.addItem(arrays.get(index))

                Log.i("TEST_TEST","$index")
                index--
                saveBitmap(arrays)

            }
        })
    }else {
        mClusterManager?.cluster()
    }
}
```

add this function after add all user you want to array list
like this

```
      override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            mGoogleMap?.clear()
            mClusterManager?.clearItems()
            var arrays=ArrayList<FirebaseUserModelMArks>()
            for(item in snapshot.children){
                var user: FirebaseUserModelMArks? 
                =item.getValue(FirebaseUserModelMArks::class.java)
                if(!user!!.firebaseID.equals(firebaseid)){
                   // mClusterManager!!.addItem(user)
                    arrays.add(user)

                    Log.i("TEST_TEST","${user.name}---------")


                        }

            }





      //      mClusterManager!!.cluster();



            saveBitmap(arrays,true)
```